# How to nullify multiple columns at specific positions?

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line, ksh

Input-

```
FN|LN|ADD|STATE|PIN|CONT|GRP|PCN|BIN|TOKEN72|TOKEN73|TOKEN74|TOKEN75|ndc|ncpdpd
FN1|LN1|ADD1|STATE1|PIN1|CONT1|GRP1|PCN1|BIN1|TOKEN721|TOKEN731|TOKEN741|TOKEN751|ndc1|ncpdpd1
FN2|LN2|ADD2|STATE2|PIN2|CONT2|GRP2|PCN2|BIN2|TOKEN722|TOKEN732|TOKEN742|TOKEN752|ndc2|ncpdpd2
```

Null the 7,8,9 columns in the above data
Output-

```
FN|LN|ADD|STATE|PIN|CONT||||TOKEN72|TOKEN73|TOKEN74|TOKEN75|ndc|ncpdpd
FN1|LN1|ADD1|STATE1|PIN1|CONT1||||TOKEN721|TOKEN731|TOKEN741|TOKEN751|ndc1|ncpdpd1
FN2|LN2|ADD2|STATE2|PIN2|CONT2||||TOKEN722|TOKEN732|TOKEN742|TOKEN752|ndc2|ncpdpd2
```

I have tried the below command
awk -F'|' 'FNR==NR{$7=" ";$8=" ";$9=" ";print}'

```
FN LN ADD STATE PIN CONT       ndc ncpdpd
FN1 LN1 ADD1 STATE1 PIN1 CONT1       ndc1 ncpdpd1
FN2 LN2 ADD2 STATE2 PIN2 CONT2       ndc2 ncpdpd2
```

I got this as an output

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? The idea of such homework tasks is to make you spend time with the problem, not let others solve it for you. I'd suggest `awk` for this, have a read on how to manipulate a field. A good guide is maintianed by [Bruce Barnett](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html).

Comment: awk  -F'|' 'FNR==NR{$7=" ";$8=" ";$9=" ";print}' A2.txt

Comment: Good start! Please update the question with this info by [editing it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/683147/edit).  What you need is setting `OFS`, the output field separator, to `|`. Use a `BEGIN` section to do so. [Reference](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-16)

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS="|"} {$7=" ";$8=" ";$9=" ";print}' I have tried this command and got the partial output

Comment: FN|LN|ADD|STATE|PIN|CONT| | | |ndc|ncpdpd
FN1|LN1|ADD1|STATE1|PIN1|CONT1| | | |ndc1|ncpdpd1
FN2|LN2|ADD2|STATE2|PIN2|CONT2| | | |ndc2|ncpdpd2
|||||| | |

Comment: I got those extra pipes(|) in the last line

Comment: please keep updating the question with this information. Also have a quick read on [how to format code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help). The extra pipes appear because there is an empty line. Now that you define fields 7 to 9, the separators are introduces. Maybe add a test for operating on non-empty lines only.

Comment: This works for me with your sample data: `awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} NF {$7=$8=$9=""} 1'`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of AWK, just use one line of Python that's much easier to read

```bsh
cat test.txt | python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write(''.join('|'.join(c for n, c in enumerate(l.split('|')) if n not in (7,8,9)) for l in sys.stdin))"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk -F "|" 'OFS="|"{$7=$8=$9="";print}' filename
```

output

```
FN|LN|ADD|STATE|PIN|CONT||||TOKEN72|TOKEN73|TOKEN74|TOKEN75|ndc|ncpdpd
FN1|LN1|ADD1|STATE1|PIN1|CONT1||||TOKEN721|TOKEN731|TOKEN741|TOKEN751|ndc1|ncpdpd1
FN2|LN2|ADD2|STATE2|PIN2|CONT2||||TOKEN722|TOKEN732|TOKEN742|TOKEN752|ndc2|ncpdpd2
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple method is

```
cat T0 | cut -f1-6,10-13 -d '|'
```

If you not sure about count of columns use

```
cat T0 | cut -f1-6,10-99 -d '|'
```

Output gonna be like this:

```
FN|LN|ADD|STATE|PIN|CONT|TOKEN72|TOKEN73|TOKEN74|TOKEN75|ndc|ncpdpd
FN1|LN1|ADD1|STATE1|PIN1|CONT1|TOKEN721|TOKEN731|TOKEN741|TOKEN751|ndc1|ncpdpd1
FN2|LN2|ADD2|STATE2|PIN2|CONT2|TOKEN722|TOKEN732|TOKEN742|TOKEN752|ndc2|ncpdpd2
```

Comment: This removes the columns altogether and does not only empty them. You may see this from the missing separators. `cut` allows "open end" definitions, i.e. `cut -f1-6,10- -d'|'` will include any field from 10 onwards. Please be aware of your use of redundant `cat`.